# 4 vertically stacked responsive divs

Tags: html, css

I admit it... I'm struggling with this one... I'm trying to make a responsive page with 4 stacked divs.

All divs are width: 100%
The header div: I want the text to display at the bottom of the div (this would be a slogan) so it appears closer to the image.
The image div: I want the image centered vertically and horizontally in the div.
The button div: I want the button (logon) at the top of the div so it appears closer to the image.
The footer div: I want to be at the absolute bottom of the page no matter what.

```
+-----------+
|           |
|           |
|  Header   |
+-----------+
|           |
|   Image   |
| (75%x75%) |
|           |
+-----------+
|  Button   |
|  <a link  |
|           |
+-----------+
+-----------+
|  Footer   |
+-----------+
```

On an iPad what I have seems to work but when I load it on a device with a smaller screen (android or iPhone 4/5) it all crumbles...

My HTML:

```
<div id="welcomePage">
    <div class="welcome">
      <div class="welcome_header">
        <h1 class="welcome">Welcome Slogan</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="welcome_image">
        <img src="logo.svg">
      </div>
      <div class="welcome_button">        
            <input type="button" value="Get Started Now!">
            <p>Already have an account? <a href="login.html">Login here</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="welcome_footer">
         <h3>&copy; 2018 BlahBlah, Inc.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.welcome {color: #5e87b0; height:100%; }
.welcome_header {width: 100%; height: 25%; min-height: 25%; display: table-header; vertical-align: text-bottom;}
.welcome_header h1{font-size:6vh;}
.welcome_image {width: 100%; margin-left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); }
.welcome_image img {border: 0; width: 75%; height: 75%;}
.welcome_button {width: 100%; height: 20%; position: absolute; clear: both; position:absolute; bottom:5%; left:0;}
.welcome_button h3 {transform: translateY(100%); bottom:0; text-align: center;}
.welcome_footer {width: 100%; height: 5%; position: fixed; clear: both; bottom: 10px; left:0;}
.welcome_footer h3{font-size:1vh;}
```

What am I missing (besides modern css skills ;-)  )?

Comment: Well... modern CSS skills, for one. That's kind of a biggie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily stack them with flex

```
#welcomePage {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#welcomePage div {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Comment: first the answer is too broad and second no need to use flex and column direction, this is the default behavior of block element. so this won't help him

Comment: @TemaniAfif he wanted to stack, and default or not it doesn't grant responsiveness.

Comment: That was perfect... got me exactly where I wanted... my welcome_button has two lines so I changed the margin-top on the 2nd and then changed the margin-bottom on the footer div to a % and works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: np, also you can use spacers (empty divs) to help position your flex items.